# Automatically check "Enable stock management at product level" to the existing products?

Tags: plugins, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on a project where the client had set "Enable stock management at the product level" uncheck to all of this products. The requirement is that checkbox has to be checked at all times. There are around 200 products and 3 websites for different countries. So if I do it manually it'll be 600 products to edit which is impossible. Is there a better way to check the box by running some functions? I looked online and apparently, only the answer is only for automatic check on product creation.

[image: Manage Stock should be checked]

Comment: you can write a script to edit the meta value of `_manage_stock` for all the products.

Comment: you can change that with the bulk edition https://nicola.blog/2015/04/21/bulk-edit-products/